# Get Application Name Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm building a module to save the data into the database. After finishing the module I will make it into a JAR which is common and anyone will call static method. There is a parameter its name application name i don’t want pass this value I want get this value dynamic after add jar to any spring boot application , then any one call this static method retrieve name application dynamic , so the spring boot contains the application properties have value **spring.application.name** I want get this value inside my module it’s doable ? it’s possible to get this value

I searched and found this implementation:

```
@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String appName;
```

My class:

```
public class BackEnd {

  @Value("${spring.application.name}")
  static String applicationName;

  private static void saveData(String messsage) {
    DAO dao= new DAO()
    dao.saveData(messsage,applicationName);
  }
}
```

So currently the `applicationName` value is `null`. Is it the correct implementation?

Comment: Why are you using static field and method? You need to have your class as a singelton bean where others can inject it, and change method and variable to be instance instead of static

Answer (score 3):

The property name is correct and used by a handful of Spring Boot projects. You need to define this property yourself as Spring Boot default is an empty value as per [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

> # IDENTITY (ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer)
>
> spring.application.name= # Application name.

You can use the usual `application.yml` file e.g.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

well, the property name is correct but you need to define that property in application.properties or application.yml file as follows.

if you are using application.properties file define property as follows

```
spring.application.name= # your application name
```

if you are using application.yml file define property as follows

```
spring:
    application:
        name: # your application name
```